# Qt 4.7 QFileSystemWatcher example

Tags: c++, qt4.7, qfilesystemwatcher

i want to observe a path with the QFileSystemWatcher in QT 4.7. In QT 5.x work my program, but I don't know why it don't work in QT 4.7.

QT 5.x

```
QFileSystemWatcher watcher;
watcher.addPath("myPath");

QStringList directoryList = watcher.directories();
Object::connect(&watcher, &QFileSystemWatcher::directoryChanged, [](const QString path){
    QDirIterator it(path, {"*"}, Dir::Files);
    while(it.hasNext()){
       // do something
    }
});
```

QT 4.7

```
QFileSystemWatcher watcher;
watcher.addPath("myPath");

QString path;
Object::connect(&watcher, &QFileSystemWatcher::directoryChanged, &path, ?{
    // do something
});
```

Can give me anyone a run able example for qt4.7?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean? Doesn't compile? Crashes? Doesn't detect changes?

Comment: I become different errors.
* main.o not found 
* if I use the code from 5.x I become -> in the global scope

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and a clear description of the problem including any error messages verbatim.